# Invoke two functions with the same name

Tags: javascript, jquery

In short i want to overwrite a javascript function with a newer one, but in that newer function i want to be able to call the old one. So for example:

```
function test()
{
    alert('original');
}

// then some time later
function test()
{
    alert('new function');
}

// call function
test();
```

In this case only the last `test()` is invoked. So the `new function` is alerted.

But is there a way to call the first `test()` method aswell? SO both `test()` function get invoked?

---

The reason i need this is because a web application generates an `onSave()` method. This function is triggered when a form is saved through Ajax.

I want to do some additional things when the form is saved but i can't just change the original `onSave()` function. That is why i'm looking for a way to extend it.

How can i do this?

Comment: Seems you are looking for `.done()` of jquery. Not sure though.

Comment: Move whatever code you need to share between the two versions in a new function and call it from both the old and new version. You'll avoid headaches when trying to make sense of your code later.

Comment: @Mr_Green Do you mean deferred? http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

Comment: @EaterOfCorpses yes I was thinking so.

Comment: @w00: What are you trying to accomplish this way? There is probably a better solution...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function test()
{
    console.log('original');
}


var test = function (oldFn) {
  // /\
  //  -------
  //        \/
  return function () { // <- return a new function which will get stored in `test`
    oldFn();                     // use the passed `oldFn`
    console.log('new function'); // the new code
  };
}(test); // <- pass in the old function, we do this, to avoid reference problems

// call function
test();
```

Comment: Thanks this seems to be doing exactly what i want. But i don't really understand the code. Why is the `return` needed in the new `test` function?

Comment: @w00 comments added. Though I'm not sure if it's enough, if not, let me know. ;)

Comment: Thanks, i understand what's going on now! :)

Comment: How would you pass an argument with test?

Comment: You just need to *accept* it with the returned function. E.g. `return function(aParam) {`

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create a new `function` and put inside the `function test()` so that when the `function test()` is called then the `new function` is called too..

e.g.

```
function test(){
 //code
 your_new_function();
}

function your_new_function(){
 //code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below instead of making same name function

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
     // do your work
});
```

You can't create two functions of same name