# Passing Variable to Self Initiating Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I found this answer that partially solved my issue, [Invoke two functions with the same name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16603985/invoke-two-functions-with-the-same-name)

My function works in the way that the first "callBackLinks" runs and then runs the //do new stuff here.

But I have a variable that would be part of my "old function" that I need to be added to the new one.

```
function callBackLinks(trgt){

     //do stuff in here with trgt

}

var callBackLinks = function(oldFn){

    return function(){
        oldFn();

        //do new stuff here
    };
}(callBackLinks);



 callBackLinks(trgt);
```

How do I get the use of the variable "trgt" in the second self initiating function?

Comment: The `var` in front of `callBackLinks` is non-operational (and misleading), I'd remove it. (In your code, not in the question.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply pass it through in your newly returned function:

```
function callBackLinks(target){
  //do stuff in here with target
}

callBackLinks = function(oldFn) {
  return function(target){
    var links = oldFn(target);
    // Do new stuff here with `target` and `links`
    // including potentially, `return links`
  };
}(callBackLinks);

callBackLinks(target);
```

If you need to work with more than two or three arguments (or if `callBackLinks` may change the arguments it accepts) you can use [`Function.prototype.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) to call `oldFn`:

```
return function(target) {
  var links = oldFn.apply(this, arguments);
  // Do things with `target` and `links` here
};
```

Then, if `callBackLinks` gets changed to accept a second `options` argument, your callers will still get the expected behavior (but you don't have to deal with arguments you don't care about).

#### Edit

I have added an example:

```js
function callBackLinks(target){
  //do stuff in here with target
  target.innerHTML += "callBackLinks called\n"
}

callBackLinks = function(oldFn) {
  return function(target){
    var links = oldFn.apply(this, arguments);
    // Do new stuff here with `target` and `links`
    // including potentially, `return links`
    target.innerHTML += "overridden function called\n"
    return links;
  };
}(callBackLinks);

callBackLinks(document.getElementById("screen"))
```

```html
<pre id="screen">
This is the screen:
</pre>
```

Comment: Or more generically if needed `return function() { return oldFn.apply(this, arguments); };`  (+1)

Comment: callBackLinks doesn't return anything. But uses the target to set things and call other functions. Basically I am trying to use this to add more code to an already existing callBack function. When I add `return function(trgt){ oldFn(trgt);}` it still doesn't recognize the trgt.

Comment: Doing this... `return function(trgt){
  oldFn(trgt);
  console.log(trgt);` spits out "callBackLinks" not the actual DOM Object it should be.

Comment: Ok never mind, you guys are right. I just looked back at the original callBack function and takes two arguments.